# # Facing Error 'Nonce not matched' and 'JSON status failed' Error

Tags: wordpress

I am using the TUTOR LMS plugin on the website

When I am trying to login this USERS dashboard they show me nonce not matched and when we do forgot password they show the error like this :

{"success":false,"data":{"message":"Nonce not matched. Action failed!"}}

Please let me know fast what i can do and how can i resolve this issue my users are facing lots of problems

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate the LiteSpeed Cache plugin.
That should fix the problem.